# Insert text at cursor position in textInput

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4.5

i need to add text at cursor position on key_up event of keyboard.
first i move cursor using arrow.
then when i was trying to write anything it goes to end of the textInput.
because i used setrange().

Here is my code sample.....

```
var view:MainView;

eventMap.mapListener(view.numDisplay,KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,onKeyBoardKeyDown);


private function onKeyBoardKeyDown(vEvent:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    view.numDisplay.selectRange(view.numDisplay.text.length, view.numDisplay.text.length);
    var cno:String=String.fromCharCode(vEvent.charCode);
    var no:String=view.numDisplay.text;
    if(no=="0") no="";
    view.numDisplay.text=no+cno;    
}
```

example:-
if i write

> hii alll

then its ok.

after that i use arrow key to move cursor.
let's say my cursor was at

> a

then if write any thing then it appears like

> hii alll123

But i need output as

> hii a123lll

Comment: why did you use selectRange() on your keyDown handler ?

Comment: Because i want the cursor always be at the end of the character. @Binou

Comment: in case of change in position i want to update the value..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know why you are using the line:

```
view.numDisplay.selectRange(view.numDisplay.text.length, view.numDisplay.text.length);
```

but maybe you can change it to

```
view.numDisplay.selectRange(view.numDisplay.caretIndex, view.numDisplay.caretIndex);
```

to set the selection to the actual cursor position so your text won't be at the end but at the correct position.

Did you try without the line ? what problem do you try to correct with this ?
With the standard behavior, the cursor is always after the last character typed. I don't understand why you want to force it to be at the end of the text.

Comment: var cursorPosition:int = view.numDisplay.selectionAnchorPosition;